# Applying spring security based upon role and user package

Tags: spring, spring-security

Our web application have different packages say (basic,essential,premium) based upon features exposed for a customer group. It also supports various roles based upon authority given to a user though, user roles are common across all the packages.

As per my knowledge we can apply security based upon user roles as follows:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/yearlyprogress/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ACCOUNTANT" />
```

However interested to know, how we can write security rule which can take customer package as parameter to apply URL authorization in correct way.